# Rank in SQL, order differently

Tags: android, sql, cursor

I'm Building an application that has a scoreboard.
The point is that the scoreboard should display the rank of the player in his class. But displayed in the order of the most recent time.

I'm trying to do this with the database select (SQL).

```
rank    name   time   class   how_recent
1.    George   2.00    V1     1 min ago
2.    Bill     3.00    V1     2 min ago
1. Christoffer 1.00    V2     3 min ago
3.   Heini.    3.00    V5     4 min ago
```

Everything but the ranking is selected from the DB. 
I have got the rank select for just the class:

```
SELECT a1._id,
       a1.name,
       a1.TIME,
       COUNT(a2.TIME) rank
FROM   players a1,
       players a2
WHERE  ( ( a1.TIME >= a2.TIME
           AND a1.TIME > 0 )
          OR ( a1.TIME > 0
               AND a1.TIME = a2.TIME
               AND a1.name = a2.name ) )
       AND a1.TIME > 0
       AND a2.TIME > 0
       AND a1.class = v1
       AND a2.class = v1
GROUP  BY a1.name,
          a1.TIME
ORDER  BY a1.TIME ASC,
          a1.name DESC
```

This i am displaying in a `simpleCursorAdapter`, my question is: 
Is it possible to get the operation done in SQL SELECT or in between the select and the `simpleCursorAdapter`?

Thanks to everyone that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the rank is the rank within each individual class.  And that the one with the shortest time has the highest ranking.

Assuming the following data:

```
create table players (time float,
                      class char(2),
                      name char(10),
                      id char(2));

insert into players values (2.0, 'V1', 'George', 1),
                           (3.0, 'V1', 'Bill', 2),
                           (1.0, 'V2', 'Chris', 3),
                           (3.0, 'V5', 'Heini', 4);
```

Then the following sql gives the ranking by lowest time within each class:

```
select a1.id, 
       a1.name, 
       a1.time,
       a1.class,
       (select count(*) 
          from players a2
          where a2.class = a1.class
          and a2.time <= a1.time) as rank
 from players a1
 order by a1.class,
          a1.time asc,
          rank desc;
```

This gives the result:

```
NAME    TIME    CLASS   RANK
George  2.0       V1    1
Bill    3.0       V1    2
Chris   1.0       V2    1
Heini   3.0       V5    1
```

By placing the 2nd join into a sub-query, you're calculating the rank for each row relative to other members within the same class.

I am confused by with Heini in your example should have rank = 3, since he's the only member of class = 'V5', so I'm assuming that's a typo and should be a 1.

Is this the kind of result you're looking for?

**--EDIT**

If you want two people who tie for 1st to be #1 and then the next one to be #3, then change this to:

```
select a1.id, 
       a1.name, 
       a1.time,
       a1.class,
       (select count(*) + 1 
          from players a2
          where a2.class = a1.class
          and a2.time < a1.time) as rank
 from players a1
 order by a1.class,
          a1.time asc,
          rank desc;
```

The time comparison is now a <, rather than a <=, which eliminates counting the matching row in the count(*), and instead add 1 back into the count.  Two that have the lowest time will both have 0 that are < than time + 1 = rank 1.  The 3rd will then have 2 that are ahead in rankings + 1 which makes them rank 3.

Comment: It works fine for displaying the table. One problem. If two persons have the best time they both get ranked 2. and the next person on the list get ranked nr. 3. I want them to both be ranked as 1. and the next person getting ranked as nr. 3. Any ideas?

Comment: See the adjustment above.  It's just a slight rework of the count(*) & where clause.